# Dataframe table in email body should be colored based on the condition in dataframe

Tags: python, html, dataframe, email, tabulate

****I want to highlight the row(out of sync) with red color so that my team can act on out of sync issues upon watching the email immediately.
Can someone help here.****
**Here is my code**

```
def bibreport():
    finaldatabib = []
    data={}
    if some condition:
        data['SyncStatus'] = "In Sync"
        finaldatabib.append(data)
    else:
        data['SyncStatus'] = "out of Sync"
        finaldatabib.append(data)

    dfbib = pd.DataFrame(finaldatabib)
    dfbib.index.name = "SNO"
    colsbib = ['SyncStatus']
    databib=dfbib
    return databib,colsbib

def sendmail(databib,colsbib):
    email_user = 'xxx@email.com'
    email_send = ['yyy@email.com']
    html = """
<html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  table, th, td {{ border: 2px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }}
  th, td {{ padding: 4px; }}
</style>
</head>
<body><p>Dear Team, </p>
<p>Please find the details below.</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>xx</p>
</body></html>
"""
    html = html.format(table=tabulate(databib, headers=colsbib ,tablefmt="html"))
    msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(html,'html')])
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = ",".join(email_send)
    msg['Subject'] = 'xxx report '+'  '+str(now.year)+"/"+str(now.month)+"/"+str(now.day)+" "+str(now.hour)+":"+str(now.minute)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpserver',25)
    print("sent to ",email_send)
    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    server.quit()
```

sendmail(databib,colsbib)

Comment: What does the function 'tabulate' does? Is it your custom function or imported one? Nevertheless you can render the table by writing your own function that iterates data frame rows one by one and returns html table: its rows and cells with desired style formatting.

Comment: I assume that you're using tabulate from https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/. It doesn't look like it supports custom HTML formatting.